# textView onClick user feedback

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-animation

How do i make a textView give the user feedback onClick

I have in my code, so that when the user clicks on a textview it saves the related data from an editText in sharedPref, however from a usability perspective there is no feedback to the user that it has been pressed and saved or not. So i am thinking some kind of user feedback is required, so the user can be sure their action has been successful. how would i achieve this, and what is the best solution?
Animate the textview? A feedback bar on the screen? A small popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest one is show user Toast with information , that action is successful. Also you can try to animate textview, but that may be easy not seen.

[Toast guide from Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts)

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Your text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, "Strength Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()    that results in an unresolved reference: context  error.

Comment: @philip taylor 'context' is your class context, replace it with 'this' and try